# ¿Como llamar el valor de un jComboBox?

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, sql-server-2014

Hago la siguiente consulta para agregar elementos al comboBox:

```
        cmbCargo.setModel(obj.LlenarCombobox("costo", "SELECT * FROM tipoServicio"));
```

(El primer valor es el campo que se muestra de la consulta)

Usando este metodo

```
        public DefaultComboBoxModel LlenarCombobox(String DisplayMemberCmb, String SelectCombo)
{
    DefaultComboBoxModel modelo = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    try
    {
        Statement st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(SelectCombo);

        while(rs.next())
        {
            modelo.addElement(rs.getString(DisplayMemberCmb));
        }
        st.close();

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexio_Metodos.LlenarCombobox Error:\n"+ex);
    }
    return modelo;
}
```

Quiero que se muestre el campo "tipoServicio" que es un Varchar que contiene una descripcion, pero trabajar en el sistema con el campo "costo" con el cual hago operaciones para obtener un costo final.

Comment: Olvide decir que el campo "costo" es un Double y ese es el que muestra el ComboBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con mis pocos conocimientos te doy mi opinión según lo que entendí de tu código tienes una tabla "costo" en la cual seleccionas todos los campos o columnas dentro de ellas si muestras el tipo de servicio y quieres trabajar con el valor de cada uno deberías primero obtener el tipo se servicio ejemplo: TIPO_SERVICIO: GAS COSTO: 00,00 debes seleccionar el servicio gas hacer una búsqueda con el nombre del servicio y obtener el valor del mismo en una variable y ya con ella trabajarías.
Para mostrar el tipo de servicio:

```
modelo.addElement(rs.getString(tipoServicio));
```

PARA SER MAS ESPECIFICO AQUI UN EJEMPLO

```
package nodelado;
```

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Nodelado {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    combo c = new combo();
}
```

}

class combo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

```
Statement stm;
ResultSet rst;
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
JButton boton = new JButton("PRECIONAME");
JTextField texto = new JTextField("0");

public combo() {
    try {
        Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://d:/modelado.accdb");
        stm = conexion.createStatement();
        rst = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tipoServicio");

        while (rst.next()) {
            combo.addItem(rst.getString("tipoServicio"));

        }
        System.out.println("CONEXION REALIZADA CON EXITO");
    } catch (SQLException sql) {
        System.out.println("ERROR AL CONECTARSE A LA BASE DE DATOS" + sql);
    }
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(300, 300);
    texto.setBounds(150,100,100,20);
    boton.setBounds(25, 150, 150, 20);
    combo.setBounds(25, 100, 100, 20);
    boton.addActionListener(this);
    add(texto);
    add(boton);
    add(combo);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Double valor = Double.parseDouble(texto.getText());
    String seleccion = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    try {
        rst = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tipoServicio WHERE (TipoServicio='" + seleccion + "')");
        while (rst.next()) {
            System.out.println(rst.getDouble("costo"));
            System.out.println("EL TOTAL ES " +(valor * rst.getDouble("costo")) );
        }

    } catch (SQLException sql) {
        System.out.println(sql);
    }
}
```

}

Lo hice usando una base de datos en access pero esa es la lógica que entendí.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en mi caso solo tengo dos registros 
[image: asumo que eso quieres hacer.]

ESPERO TE SIRVA DE AYUDA.

Comment: Gracias amigo, esto me sirvio

Comment: De nada siempre hay que compartir conocimientos.